# Creating a dict from list of key, value tuples while maintaining duplicate keys

Tags: python

So I've got a comprehension to the effect of:

```
dict((x.key, x.value) for x in y)
```

The problem, of course, is that if there's multiple `x.key`s with the same value, they get collapsed with the last `x.value` with that particular `x.key` as the only surviving member. I want to actually make the values of the resulting dict a list:

```
{
    'key1': ['value1'],
    'key2': ['value2', 'value3', 'value4'],
    'key3': ['value5'],
    # etc.
}
```

Is this logic possible with a comprehension?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can add the elements one by one to a dictionary that contains empty lists by default:

```
import collections

result_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for x in y:
    result_dict[x.key].append(x.value)
```

You can also do something very similar without having to use the collections module:

```
result_dict = {}
for x in y:
    result_dict.setdefault(x.key, []).append(x.value)
```

but this is arguably slightly less legible.

An equivalent, more legible (no need to "parse" the less common `setdefault`) but more pedestrian, base Python approach is:

```
result_dict = {}
for x in y:
    if x.key not in result_dict:
        result_dict[x.key] = []
    result_dict[x.key].append(x.value)
```

The first solution is clearly the preferred one, as it is at the same time concise, legible, and fast.

Comment: From the docs, I presume it's safe to treat defaultdict exactly as a dict after the fact? Also, in your second example, the method is actually `setdefault` not `set_default`. Anyways, I think both methods are equally legible, honestly, so it really boils down to if it's better to have a true-blue dict than a defaultdict.

Comment: You want a `defaultdict`.  It's a first-class, does-everything-else-the-same, real honest-to-goodness dictionary.  No "safe to treat" hand-wringing.  It **is** a dict with a different `__getitem__`.    The `setdefault` version is less good for this application.

Comment: @chrisdpratt: Thanks for the typo fix.  Yeah, defaultdict can be treated pretty much like dict.  This only thing I can think of from the top of my head is that any item access `result_dict[…]` will create a new key if the key does not exist.  Most of the time, this is not a problem, indeed.

Comment: In this application, I don't think it will be. I won't need to really access the keys directly, just iterate over the set.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. You cannot do this in a comprehension.

But you can use `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: I think EOL's solution is more straight-forward so far, but +1 for creativity ;).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not saying it's the right thing to do, but, just out of sheer intellectual curiosity..

You can use `itertools.groupby` and `lambda` to do it in one dict comprehension, if that's what you really want to do: (where `l` is the list of tuples you want to make a `dict` out of:

```
dict((k, [v[1] for v in vs]) for (k, vs) in itertools.groupby(l, lambda x: x[0]))
```

Comment: `groupby()` requires the keys to be *sorted*, if you want it to work as you intend.

Comment: I see that now, oh well, it was only a curiosity anyway!

Comment: @Hoons I upvote because I first believe that your expression was wrong, but I realized that it's OK. I apparently still don't master groupby's functionning. Though, this solution with groupby isn't the better for this problem IMO.

Comment: The 'functional programming' version of the solution with groupby is: ``dict(map(lambda (k,g): (k,map(itemgetter(1),tuple(g))) ,groupby(sorted(map(lambda x: (x.key, x.value), y)),key=itemgetter(0))))`` Ouch !