# Python dictionary with same keys

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a python list which contains dictionaries and I want to make a new list which contain dictionaries with unique keys and associated list values like below:

```
Input:
 [{1: 2}, {2: 2}, {1: 3}, {2: 1}, {1: 3}]
Output:
 [{1:[2,3,3]},{2:[2,1]}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does every unique key also contain itself in the list? I'm just wondering how the list `[1,2,3]` is formed since I must be missing something.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Can we dispense with that URL? Better use something like [this script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) and write more verbose recommendations to include more information on what the OP has tried, optionally with a link to that article.

Comment: @jamylak it was a typo in output

Comment: You can adapt [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795361/creating-a-dict-from-list-of-key-value-tuples-while-maintaining-duplicate-keys/6795385#6795385) to do what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
input = [{1: 2}, {2: 2}, {1: 3}, {2: 1}, {1: 3}]

r = {}
for d in input:
    # (assumes just one key/value per dict)
    ((x, y),) = d.items() 
    r.setdefault(x, []).append(y)

print [ {k: v} for (k, v) in r.items() ]
```

Result:

```
[{1: [2, 3, 3]}, {2: [2, 1]}]
```

[update]

> just curious : Can you explain whats going on in `((x, y),) = d.items()` and `r.setdefault(x, []).append(y)` ? – [damned](https://stackoverflow.com/users/713495/damned)

First the `((x, y),) = d.items()`:

- at this point, d will be an element from `input`, like `{1: 2}`
- `d.items()` will be something analogous to `[(1, 2)]`
- in order to unpack 1 and 2 into x and y, we need the extra `,` (otherwise the interpreter will think the outer parenthesis are doing grouping instead of defining a single element tuple)

The `r.setdefault(x, []).append(y)` is analogous to:

```
if not r.has_key(x):
     r[x] = []
r[x].append(y)
```

Comment: just curious : Can you explain whats going on in `((x, y),) = d.items()` and `r.setdefault(x, []).append(y)` ?

Answer (score 3):

Trick is to use dict.setdefault to start off a list and append to it:

```
input = [{1: 2}, {2: 2}, {1: 3}, {2: 1}, {1: 3}]
output = {}
for d in input:
    for k,v in d.items():
        output.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

# output contains {1: [2, 3, 3], 2: [2, 1]}

output=[{k:v} for k,v in output.items()]

# output contains [{1: [2, 3, 3]}, {2: [2, 1]}]
```

What setdefault does is return either the existing list keyed by 'k', or if that key does not exist in the dictionary, it creates a new entry for that key with the second argument and returns that. Either way it returns the list whether it was pre-existing or new, so that you can then append to it.

Comment: My output was [{1:[2,3,3]},{2:[2,1]}] not {1: [2, 3, 3], 2: [2, 1]}

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> lis=[{1: 2}, {2: 2}, {1: 3}, {2: 1}, {1: 3}]
>>> new_lis=[{}]
>>> for x in lis:
    for y in x:
       if y in new_lis[0]:
           new_lis[0][y].append(x[y])
           new_lis[0][y].sort()
       else :new_lis[0][y]=[x[y]]


>>> new_lis
[{1: [2, 3, 3], 2: [1, 2]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> data = [{1: 2}, {2: 2}, {1: 3}, {2: 1}, {1: 3}]
... 
... from itertools import groupby
... 
... keyFn = lambda x: x.keys()[0]
... 
... [{k: [i.values()[0] for i in g]} for k, g in groupby(sorted(data, key=keyFn), keyFn)]
0: [{1: [2, 3, 3]}, {2: [2, 1]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output = []
for b in a:
  added = 0
  i = 0
  for c in output:
    if b.keys()[0] in c.keys():
       output[i][b.keys()[0]].append(b[b.keys()[0]])
       added = 1
    i += 1

  if not added:
    output.append({b.keys()[0]: [b[b.keys()[0]]]})
```

Comment: In your example, what is ls? (for c in ls:).

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out. That was a type. `ls` is actually `output`.