# Dictionary/Tuples in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

My purpose is to convert this list of pairs:

```
[(9, 7), (78, 24), (17, 74), (53, 81), (40, 43), (79, 82), (84, 46), (68, 53),(92, 95), (60, 38), (78, 62), (72, 57)]
```

To this dictionary:

```
{'78': [24,62], '53': [81], '92': [95], '68': [53], '17': [74], '9': [7], '40': [43], '84': [46], '60': [38], '79': [82], '72': [57]}
```

Here is my code:

```
def convert list_tuples_to_dictionary(lst):
    global count
    count={}
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        x=str(lst[i][0])
        if (x in count):
            count[x]=[lst[i][1]]+count[x]
        else:    
        count[x]=[lst[i][1]]
```

I seem to have a syntax error somewhere. I'm guessing I cannot use list as keys in dictionary. Is this is the case?

If yes, can you offer an alternative?

Comment: lists are mutable therefore not hashable (try: `hash([])`). keys in a dict need to be hashable.

Comment: @matiaselgart what is the relevance of that comment? OP is not using lists as keys.

Comment: Invalid Syntax in : count[x]=[lst[i][1]]+count[x]

Comment: @DanielRoseman OP asked: `I'm guessing I cannot use list as keys in dictionary.Is this is the case?`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a dict from list of key, value tuples while maintaining duplicate keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795361/creating-a-dict-from-list-of-key-value-tuples-while-maintaining-duplicate-keys)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
data = [(9, 7), (78, 24), (17, 74), (53, 81), (40, 43), (79, 82), (84, 46), (68, 53),(92, 95), (60, 38), (78, 62), (72, 57)]

count = {}
for i in data:
    if not i[0] in count:
        count[i[0]] = []
    count[i[0]].append(i[1])
```

Comment: It gives me an error in this line: count[i[0]].append(i[1])

Answer (score 4):

```
 from collections import defaultdict
 res = defaultdict(list)
 for k, v in lst: res[k].append(v)
```

`default_dict` is a dictionary implementation that works in such way that if a key is not already present, it is created automatically (with usual `dict` you would get a  `keyError`). In `res` you will find the the values grouped by the key, and this is basically a `groupByKey` operation.

Comment: I'm almost sure it should be `for v, k in lst: res[v].append(k)`

Comment: Yeah, the concept was obvious I think.

Comment: Will be nice if you provide a complete example (also - the result here is not what the OP was looking for) and also an explanation. Currently it's only a piece of code (and not one that answer the question).

Comment: At the end, the OP asked for an alternative, and this is a good alternative to me.

Comment: This is a poor quality answer if you don't explain what you choose this, what is `defaultdict`, how to use it, etc.